# How should I follow the code below to select the date and month from a single datepicker?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net-core

```
<div class="col-md-3 pull-left" style="padding:9px">
                    <select id="year" class="form-control">
                        @for (int i = date.Year; i >= date.Year - 3; i--)
                        {
                            if (i == date.Year)
                            {
                                <option selected value="@i">@i</option>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <option value="@i">@i</option>
                            }
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 pull-left" style="padding:9px">
                    <select id="month" class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">January</option>
                        <option value="2">February</option>
                        <option value="3">March</option>
                        <option value="4">April</option>
                        <option value="5">May</option>
                        <option value="6">June</option>
                        <option value="7">July</option>
                        <option value="8">August</option>
                        <option value="9">September</option>
                        <option value="10">October</option>
                        <option value="11">November</option>
                        <option value="12">December</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

> The codes consisting of html and css that I shared above are in a select tag. I want to remove this select tag and have only datepicker. But it has to be dynamic. The dynamism is also provided by the following javascript codes. I want a solution from you so that the records I want come after selecting a month and year from the datepicker. Thank you for your support.

```
var getyear = @date.Year;
        var getmonth = @date.Month;
        $("#month").val("@ViewBag.MONTH");
        $("#year").val("@ViewBag.YEAR");

        function setdatas() {
            location.href = "?year=" + $("#year").val() + "&month=" + $("#month").val();
        }

        $("#year").change(function () {
            setdatas();
        });
        $("#month").change(function () {
            setdatas();
        });
```

> This code is the javascript code linked to the above code.

Comment: Do you want to select only date and month from picker?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Do you consider `javascript` or only `cshtml`?

Comment: Thinking with Javascript

Comment: Okay got it, let me help you this.

Comment: Hope this will meet your requirements:  http://jsfiddle.net/78526Nasir/k92psvnd/

Comment: @NasirIslamSujan, yes that's the solution, I was preparing. Anyway, Ismail you can implement that.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the javascript codes, how can we change this because I tried the method you posted.

Comment: @NasirIslamSujan Please consider adding an answer to this question here. You can use stack snippets for HTML, JavaScript and CSS based code.

Comment: What do you wanted to implement eventually? First want to select year, then date and month then what do you wanted to do? Why you are again retrieving the value explicitly once more? What do you want to pass to your controller finally?

Comment: After selecting a date and month from the datepicker, I want to get information about the relevant date and month.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Thank you for your support on how I can follow a way to do what I want above.

Answer (score 0):

To make a datepicker with only date and month, you can take help of [jQuery Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/):

On the below code snippet I set `changeYear` property to `false` and add css to hide the default Year text.

```css
.ui-datepicker-year {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
<input type="text" name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
          changeDay: true,
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: false,
          dateFormat: 'dd MM',
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work on my program